# How to align two elements horizontally in line

Tags: html, css, alignment

I am looking for the to align two divs horizontally.

One div in the dead center of the screen (horizontally) and the other one in the right of it. I want both of them to be on the same line.

I want to achieve this:

[image: layout]

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 10px;
  color: wheat;
  text-align: center;
}

.b1 {
  margin: auto;
}

.b2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box b1">box1</div>
<div class="box b2">box2</div>
```

Is this a reliable and responsive way to do this?
I want a general method where I can have one element in the center of the screen and another
one maybe to the right or to the left.
I was thinking about using flexbox but I don't know how to position the first element in the center and move the other one around freely without affecting the first one.

Comment: Works fine, however you should wrap the boxes in a container that has `position: relative` as otherwise the right box will always be at the top right corner of the website not necesarily in line with the other div.

Comment: In this example, the box to the right has a top margin of 10px, while the one on the middle has none, so it "inherits" the body's top margin of 8px.